# What size of SIM card Nexus 7 2013 LTE TMo comes with?

Tags: nexus-7, 4g

I cannot find any mention of which SIM the [newest Nexus 7 32GB 2013 LTE TMo](https://play.google.com/store/devices/details/Nexus_7_32GB_WiFi_Mobile_data_Unlocked_T_Mobile_SI?id=nexus_7_32gb_2013_lte_tmo) comes with.

Is it Mini-SIM?  Micro-SIM?  Nano-SIM?

The page only mentions that it comes with a `SIM ejection tool` and has `Micro USB`.

Comment: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3256561

Comment: Why is the question downvoted?  Is this information on the SIM card size of the device somehow available on the official page I've referenced that I've missed?

Comment: @cnst - I suspect people are downvoting because the answer is pretty easily obtainable via a google search for `nexus 7 sim card size`, the first result for which is the link  eldarerathis gave in their comment.

Answer (score 1):

According to [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/asus_google_nexus_7_%282013%29-5600.php), the Nexus 7 2013 uses a microSIM.

[Google's help page on inserting the SIM further confirms this](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3256561).

I would fully expect that Google would include a SIM of the appropriate size, unless they've completely reneged on their "Don't be evil" bit.

If not, just break out your scissors to cut it down to the appropriate size and shape.  The extra size is just empty plastic to make handling easier.  The only important bits are directly under the connector.

Comment: Well, my question was of what the appropriate size is.  It's not mentioned on the page.

Comment: The appropriate size is microSIM.  And unless Google is being mean, a microSIM is what they'd include with the tablet.

Comment: You're unfairly making fun of my question.  I'm not asking if they include a SIM card that's compatible with the tablet, that'd be a dumb question indeed.

Comment: @cnst - I'm not intentionally trying to make fun of it.  I'm just apparently misunderstanding what exact information you're asking for.

Comment: I'm just asking for the information that any decent manufacturer includes right on the specs page of their product, that's it.  E.g. http://www.apple.com/ipad-2/specs/ is pretty clear about saying `Micro-SIM card tray (Wi‑Fi + 3G model)`, whereas there is no such mention on the Google spec pages for Nexus 7.

Comment: @Compro01 Even less than that! :> Take a look at new iPad Mini / iPad Air / iPhone 5 and their nanoSIM cards. If you use proper card cutter to cut SIM/microSIM cards to nanoSIM size, you'll clearly see, that outer parts of connector itself are also cut-off. I was shocked at first to find this out! :>